# Why new DateTime(nulll refrence) returns current date?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

The following code prints current date. Is there any way in Joda DateTime API to return null if null reference passed in.
Thanks for help.

```
 class MyDateExtractor{
        private Date date;
        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }

    public class DateTimeTest {
        @Test
        public void testName() throws Exception {
            MyDateExtractor date = new MyDateExtractor();
            System.out.println(new DateTime(date.getDate()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually read the error?

Comment: a constructor always creates and initialises the object you asked it to construct. Only a factory method can choose which (or whether) to return an object.

Comment: Couldnt you just check the value of `date.getDate()` before passing it to the constructor?

Comment: What is the compilaton error you get? I would expect it to be a runtime error.

Comment: BTW I suggest you use the JSR-310 library which largely replaces Joda Time

Comment: Based on the description, I'd expect that `new DateTime(null)` results in ambiguous constructor call at compile time. Yup.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have asked about new DateTime(null). My actual point is why new DateTime(date.getDate()) where date.getDate()=null returns current date?

Comment: The `new` operator can never return `null`. It either returns a new object or throws an exception (or error; or hangs).

Answer (score 2):

[DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) has (among others) the constructors `DateTime(Chronology)`, `DateTime(DateTimeZone)` and `DateTime(Object)`. If you pass in a null, it's not clear which one you mean and the compiler gives you an error.

If you use `new DateTime(date.getDate())`, the runtime value will be null, but the compiler can determine a constructor to call (the one with `Object` param, since there's nothing more specific).

Calling the `DateTime(Object)` [constructor](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(java.lang.Object)) with a null parameter gives you the current date/time.